# How to rearrange the sort buttons in a view

Tags: views, theming, 8

There don't appear to be any Twig templates that allow you to move the exposed sort buttons to a different location in the view display. Does anybody know if these templates do actually exist?

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a twig for the exposed sort form. But normally you rearrange form elements inside of a form by adjusting the weight property. If you want to move the button outside of the form in another place of the view you need some tricks, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag/23456905

If you want to rearrange the view in general, like moving the complete exposed section to another place, you can do this in `views-view.html.twig`:

```
{{ title_prefix }}
  {{ title }}
  {{ title_suffix }}

  {% if header %}
    <header>
      {{ header }}
    </header>
  {% endif %}

  {{ exposed }}
  {{ attachment_before }}

  {{ rows }}
  {{ empty }}
  {{ pager }}

  {{ attachment_after }}
  {{ more }}

  {% if footer %}
    <footer>
      {{ footer }}
    </footer>
  {% endif %}

  {{ feed_icons }}
```

Comment: What I'm looking for exactly is to move the sort-by element below the submit button...so sort-by and order-by can be styled as if they were outside the filter box.

Comment: The first part is no problem, you can change the order of the form elements by adjusting the weight property in a form alter hook. For the second part you need someone with good CSS skills or use a trick from the linked SO question.

Comment: I managed to do exactly what I wanted in the views-exposed-form.html.twig file by drilling down into the form variable and outputting the form's sub-variables as I needed.